# Overloading += operator in Polynom class for adding both Polynoms and constants

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to overload `+=` operator for my template Polynom class in a way so I would be able to use both Polynoms and constants as argument.

I wrote a constructor and following operator inside my class:

```
Polynom(const T& num = 0) {
  coefs.push_back(num);
}
friend Polynom& operator += (Polynom& lhs, const Polynom& rhs) {
  ...
}
```

And it works fine, I am able to use: `poly += 1;`. When compiler runs into something likes that what does it do? It sees that there is no += operator that uses these arguments:

```
(Polynom<int>& lhs, const int)
```

But there is one for:

```
(Polynom<int>& lhs, const Polynom& rhs)
```

So, it tries to convert `const int` to `const Polynom&`? And it uses constructor for that, right? But then why doesn't this declaration work when adding a constant:

```
Polynom& operator += (Polynom& rhs) {
  ...
}
```

Compiler says "no match for operator +=".

Comment: Your member `operator+=` should probably take a `const Polynom&` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing an `int` to a function taking a `const Polynom&`, the compiler is able to construct a temporary `Polynom` object from the `int` that is then bound to the `const Polynom&` parameter. However this doesn't happen with the `Polynom&` parameter because temporaries cannot be bound to non const references.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600. This explains my problem, right? It is just a rule that I can't bind a non-const ref to temp object.

Comment: @grozhd yes it's just  one of the rules in the standard. Those answers explain it in much more detail

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us the template code or your smallest compilable code that demonstrates the issue.

Try creating a method that accepts an integer parameter:

```
friend Polynom& operator+=(const Polynom& lhs, int constant);
```

I'm confused about your notation `Polynom<int>` which indicates your `Polynom` class is a template.